# Random But Unique Pairings, with Conditions

Tags: php, random

I need some help/direction in setting up a PHP script to randomly pair up items in an array.

- The items should be randomly paired up each time.
- The items should not match themselves ( item1-1 should not pair up with item1-1 )
- **Most** of the items have a mate (*ie.* item1-1 and item1-2).  The items should not be paired with their mate.

I've been playing around with [the second script in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758223/using-php-randomly-pair-up-group-of-items-not-pairing-any-with-itself-no-direc) but, I haven't been able to make any progress.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Thought I'd fix this in a minute or two, but I may need some more. Tough question. What do you need it for?

Comment: @GolezTrol - Non-profit side project.  Matching up people/couples for an event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple approach, but hopefully helpful to you:

(*mates*, if grouped in an array (e.g. *array('a1', 'a2')*), will not be paired.)

```
function matchUp($array) {
  $result = array();

  while($el = array_pop($array)) {
    shuffle($array);

    if (sizeof($array) > 0) {
      $candidate = array_pop($array);

      $result[] = array(
        array_pop($el),
        array_pop($candidate)
      );

      if (sizeof($el) > 0) {
        $array[] = $el;
      }

      if (sizeof($candidate) > 0) {
        $array[] = $candidate;
      }
    }
    else {
      $result[] = array(array_pop($el));
    }
  }

  return $result;
}

$array = array(
  array('a1', 'a2'),
  array('b1', 'b2'),
  array('c1'),
  array('d1'),
  array('e1', 'e2'),
  array('f1'),
  array('g1', 'g2'),
);
```

**Update**:

```
foreach(matchUp($array) as $pair) {
  list($a, $b) = $pair + array(null, null);
  echo '<div style="border: solid 1px #000000;">' . $a . ' + ' . $b . '</div>';
}
```

Comment: That's excellent and seems to work perfectly.  How do I setup a foreach statement to pull the values from the array?  For example - 'C1 is matched with D2' and on down the list

Comment: Just use the result from matchUp as parameter for a foreach (like: `foreach(matchup($array) as $pair) {}` The only thing to do now is check $pair to contain 1 or 2 elements.

Comment: I tried that and it's only returning the word "Array".  See the example code above.  Also, how do I grab each individual result, within each pair?  Instead of returning 'D1, D3', I'd like to grab the values individually so I can manipulate them (ie. 'D1 got D3').  Grabbing data, within an array, within another array, is where I'm getting confused.

Comment: @Batfan I included an foreach example. But I would urge you to read up on array handling/usage, as this is really basic stuff. reference: [Arrays](http://php.net/manual/language.types.array.php)

Comment: I had actually looked over that page but, didn't see any references to an Array within another Array.  Seeing your example is really helpful.  Thanks so much for the help and insight.  Very appreciated

Answer (score 1):

With the randomness, there is no guarantee that a full correct solution will be reached.

Certain problem sets are more likely to be solved than others. Some will be impossible.

You can configure how many times it will try to achieve a good solution. After the specified number of tries it will return the best solution it could find.

```
function pairUp (array $subjectArray) {
    // Config options
    $tries = 50;

    // Variables
    $bestPaired = array();
    $bestUnpaired = array();

    for($try = 1; $try <= 50; $try++) {
        $paired = array();
        $unpaired = array();
        $toBePaired = $subjectArray;

        foreach($subjectArray as $subjectIndex => $subjectValue) {
            // Create array without $thisValue anywhere, from the unpaired items
            $cleanArray = array();
            foreach($toBePaired as $index => $value) {
                if($value != $subjectValue) {
                    array_push($cleanArray, array(
                        'index' => $index,
                        'value' => $value
                    ));
                }
            }
            sort($cleanArray); // reset indexes in array

            // See if we have any different values left to match
            if(count($cleanArray) == 0) {
                array_push($unpaired, $subjectValue);
                continue;
            }

            // Get a random item from the clean array
            $randomIndex = rand(0,count($cleanArray)-1);
            // Store this pair
            $paired[$subjectIndex] = $subjectValue . '-' . $cleanArray[$randomIndex]['value'];
            // This item has been paired, remove it from unpairedItems
            unset($toBePaired[$cleanArray[$randomIndex]['index']]);
            sort($toBePaired);
        }

        // Decide if this is our best try
        if(count($paired) > count($bestPaired)) {
            $bestPaired = $paired;
            $bestUnpaired = $unpaired;
        }

        // If we had no failures, this was a perfect try - finish
        if(count($unpaired) == 0) { $break; }
    }

    // We're done, send our array of pairs back.
    return array(
        'paired' => $bestPaired,
        'unpaired' => $bestUnpaired
    );
}

var_dump(pairUp(array('a','b','c','d','e','a','b','c','d','e')));
/*
Example output:
array(2) {
  ["paired"]=>
  array(10) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "a-b"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "b-c"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "c-d"
    [3]=>
    string(3) "d-e"
    [4]=>
    string(3) "e-a"
    [5]=>
    string(3) "a-b"
    [6]=>
    string(3) "b-e"
    [7]=>
    string(3) "c-d"
    [8]=>
    string(3) "d-c"
    [9]=>
    string(3) "e-a"
  }
  ["unpaired"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
*/
```

Comment: I'm afraid this code doesn't consider the fact that some elements may have mates with which they shouldn't be paired.

Comment: @Robin - Thanks for the effort but, Jong is correct.  Still needs to enforce the rule about their mates

Comment: Oh I see. As in there might be two 'a's. Fair enough, I'll try to take that into account.

Comment: I've updated (well more like completely changed) my solution. Take a look, I think it works now.

Comment: @Robin - Maybe I'm missing something.  Aren't some of the letters being matched more than once?  For instance, in your example results, C-E and C-B

Comment: That's an easier problem I think. I thought you just didn't want a-a, or b-b, but you still wanted a-g and a-c (if there were two 'a's in the original array)

Comment: So to clarify, if the original array is [A, B, C, D, A, B, C, D] you just want (for example) [A-B, B-D, C-A, D-C]?

Comment: Well I'm going to bed. If you wanted just random unique pairings you could have used my original script, just removed all duplicates first. That would have been a much easier problem.

Comment: @Robin - How does it determine which values have mates?  It would appear that its relying on the values being the same.

Comment: @Batfan I don't understand what you mean. Could you explain with input and output examples? Potentially edit your original question to make it more clear exactly what you expect.

Comment: @Robin - So, for example: the mate for 'A' might be 'D'.  As I said, I don't want mates to be paired up so, obviously the mates would need to be defined somewhere.  Where is that happening?  In your script, it looks like your automatically assuming that the mate for 'A' is another 'A'

Comment: As I said, can you give me an example of an input set and an output set? What my script does is goes through a list of items and attempts find a mate for all items that 1) aren't itself and 2) aren't the same as itself. So a mate for "a" might be "c". And if there are two "a"s, a mate for the second might be "d". The "a"s will never be matched with each other. Please explain with examples of *full* input and output sets what you are expecting.

Comment: @Robin - Yoshi's example accomplished what I was looking for.  Thanks for the assistance though

Comment: Cool. I'm glad @Yoshi understood your question better than I did.

Answer (score 1):

**Case 1: if all elements had a mate**

If all elements had a mate, the following solution would work, although I don't know if it would be perfectly random (as in, all possible outputs having the same probability):

1. Shuffle the list of elements, keeping mates together

   ```
    original list = (a1,a2),(b1,b2),(c1,c2),(d1,d2)
    shuffled      = (c1,c2),(d1,d2),(a1,a2),(b1,b2)
   ```
2. Shift the second mate to the right. The matches have been formed.

   ```
    shifted       = (c1,b2),(d1,c2),(a1,d2),(b1,a2)
   ```

(Edit1: if applied exactly as described, there is no way `a1` ends up matched with `b1`. So, before shifting, you may want to throw a coin for each pair of mates to decide whether they should change their order or not.)

**Case 2: if only some elements have a mate**

Since in your question only some elements will have a mate, I guess one could come up with the following:

1. Arbitrarily pair up those elements who don't have a mate. There should be an even number of such elements. Otherwise, the total number of elements would be odd, so no matching could be done in the first place.

   ```
   original list = (a1,a2),(b1,b2),c1,d1,e1,f1  // c1,d1,e1 and f1 don't have mates
   list2         = (a1,a2),(b1,b2),(c1,d1),(e1,f1) // pair them up
   ```
2. Shuffle and shift as in case 1 to form the matches.

   ```
   shuffled = (e1,f1),(a1,a2),(c1,d1),(b1,b2) 
   shifted  = (e1,b2),(a1,f1),(c1,a2),(b1,d1)
   ```

Again, I don't know if this is perfectly random, but I think it should work.

(Edit2: simplified the solution)

(Edit3: if the total number of elements is odd, someone will be left without a match, so pick an element randomly at the beginning to leave it out and then apply the algorithm above).