# php compare arrays for pairing people (with conditions)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, multiple-conditions

I am writing a PHP script that is for a essentially a gift grab-bag (pulling names out of a hat). But there's a few conditions:
-You cannot be paired with your spouse
-You cannot have who you had last year
-You cannot have yourself (obviously)

I wrote a code to the likes of:

```
// I'm using a multidimensional array so I can check the spouses
$array = array(
  array('Husband1', 'Wife1'),
  array('Husband2', 'Wife2'),
  array('Husbad3', 'Wife3'),
  array('Single1'),
  array('Single2'),
);

// if you were to sort the above array - here is their recipients lastYear
$lastYear = array(
'Single1', 
'Husbad3',
'Single2',
'Wife3',
'Husband1',
'Wife2',
'Husband2',
'Wife1',
);

// declaring an empty values
$that = array();
$n = 0;

// converts multidimensional array to 2 identical arrays
for ($row = 0; $row < count($array); $row++)
{
        for ($col = 0; $col < 2; $col++)
        {
                if (isset($array[$row][$col]))
                {
                    $toList[] = $array[$row][$col];
                    $fromList[] = $array[$row][$col];
                }

        }
}

echo "Last Year \n";

 // creates a list for last year
 for ($row = 0; $row < count($toList); $row++)
 {
  echo $toList[$row] . " had " . $lastYear[$row] . "\n";
 }

// randomly mixes up the to the toList
shuffle($toList);

echo "This Year \n";

// pairs the multidimensional array 1 index at a time
for ($row = 0; $row < count($array); $row++)
{

    for ($col = 0; $col < 2; $col++)
    {
         // if it exists then print it out
         if (isset($array[$row][$col]))
         {

              // if the toList index is the same person (as in $array), or already paired (in $that array), or a spouse (in $array), or the same person as last year - RESHUFFLE
              while ($array[$row][$col] == $toList[$row] or in_array($toList[$row], $that) or in_array($toList[$row],$array[$row]) or $toList[$row] == $lastYear[$row])
              {
                    // if it takes more then 200 Shuffles - BREAK
                    if ($n > 200)
                {
                 echo "I'm Broke!! \n";
                 exit;
                }
            shuffle($toList);
            $n++;
           }

         // once you find a match, add it to $that array and move on
         $that[] = $toList[$row];   
         echo $array[$row][$col] . " has " . $toList[$row] . "\n";
         }

    }
}
```

I found similar solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239598/php-how-to-pair-up-items-in-array-based-on-condition) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085140/random-but-unique-pairings-with-conditions), but they didn't have the same conditions I did. There may be a better way to handle the errors too, but this gets the job done after a few re-runs.

My problem is, sometimes it pairs with the same person you had last year (Most commonly the last result is paired with the same both years). What is wrong with my while loop?

I assume the following while statement:

```
 $toList[$row] == $lastYear[$row]
```

isn't being interpreted how I want it to. But It seems theoretically correct.

Comment: That looks like a party I want to be invited to.

Comment: I don't have time right now to write up a full answer, but the logic in the while statement is very wrong.  You're referencing $toList[$row], even though $row is the loop for $array.  I think you'd be better off creating a couple of assoc arrays (name -> spouse, name -> last year's "to"); that would make it easier to look up an invalid match.

Comment: @Joe I see what you mean. I may try to rewrite it with associative arrays. Couldn't I create a new parameter to substitute for row? or is that making a mountain out of a mole hill?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
$lastYear = array(
    "Husband1"  => "Single1",
    "Wife1"     => "Husbad3",
    "Husband2"  => "Single2",
    "Wife2"     => "WIfe3",
    "Husbad3"   => "Husband1",
    "Wife3"     => "Wife2",
    "Single1"   => "Husband2",
    "Single2"   => "Wife1");

$spouses = array(
  'Husband1'    => 'Wife1',
  'Husband2'    => 'Wife2',
  'Husbad3'     => 'Wife3',
  'Single1'     => null,
  'Single2'     => null);

// Add corresponding spouses to $spouses
foreach($spouses as $key => $value)
    if($value !==null)
        $spouses[$value] = $key;

$thisYear = array();    // To hold this year's assignments
$tos = array();         // Temp var to hold potential assignment

$iterations=0;          // Count number of times through the loop (fail after 100)
do
{
    $success=true;      // will set to false if anyone can't be assigned

    foreach(array_keys($lastYear) as $key)
    {
        $thisYear[$key] = null;     // null out all "to"s
        $tos[] = $key;              // create temp array with copy of "from" list 
    }

    // go through each "from" person
    foreach(array_keys($thisYear) as $from)
    {
        // shuffle the "to" array which contains remaining potential "to" people
        shuffle($tos);

        // start with the last item in $to[].  If it's ineligible for any reason, then we'll check the previous one, and so on
        $checkTo=count($tos)-1;
        do
        {
            $to = $tos[$checkTo];
            if($to !== $from
                && $spouses[$from] !== $to
                && $lastYear[$from] !== $to)
            {
                // $to is an eligible assignment for $from.  Add it to $thisYear, and remove it from $tos[]
                $thisYear[$from] = $to;
                array_splice($tos,$checkTo,1);  
                break;
            }
        } while (--$checkTo >= 0);

        // if checkTo < 0, then there are no eligible assignments for $from.  Set $success=false so we'll try again
        if($checkTo<0)
        {
            $success=false;
            break;
        }
    }
} while($success==false && $iterations++ < 100);

foreach($thisYear as $key => $value)
    echo "$key is assigned to $value<br>";
```