# PHP match an array into itself randomatically

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, list

#### sample array:

```
$player = array("lawrence","joey","jason","joel","bianca","paulo","albert");
```

i want to match an array to itself so that it gets a value from itself without getting a duplicated value:

```
"lawrence" => "lawrence"; //must not contain itself
"joey" => "lawrence"; //must not assign value already assigned to that value
```

in a **NUTSHELL:**
its like a Exchange Gift Algorithm

Comment: `i want to match an array to itself so that it gets a value from itself without getting a duplicated value:` Can you please say this in *English*?

Comment: Do you want... to randomly select values from your array and not have it repeat the values it selects?

Comment: yes precicely @gloomy.penguin with addition that the selected values cannot be selected a second time

Comment: I was thinking the goal was like an OUTER JOIN, where the players should be paired... can you give an example of what *would* work in addition to the two examples that don't?  And @HankyPanky - Give the OP a point for the best new English word of the week. Randomatically is the coolest thing I've seen in some time.

Comment: Exchange Gift Algorithm --- you mean like a secret santa?

Comment: have you tried anything to solve this on your own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$player = array("lawrence","joey","jason","joel","bianca","paulo","albert");
shuffle($player);
$player2 = $player;
array_unshift($player2, array_pop($player2));

$combined = array_combine($player, $player2);
```

Shuffle it, transpose it by 1 to create guaranteed unique matches, recombine.

Comment: Is this the Outer Join idea I had in mind? (limit one per array member?)

Comment: I don't think it's the same idea. This simply rotates the array one position and recombines it.

Comment: its good but it has a pattern, have to add random effect on it

Comment: So like a secret santa?

Comment: @Lawrence The only pattern is that there's an order in the array of *a > b, b > c*, there's no pattern between *a* and *b* or *b* and *c*. Shuffle it again after the combine to remove that chain.

Comment: @deceze - This is apparently called a derangement, which i find delightful on it's own. The math looks over my head, but it might lend itself to a more "natural" pairing.

Comment: @deceze ahh i understand now, i think it will work just fine then

Comment: Actually, a derangement only covers permutations where none of the original set members are in the same position (or in the case of the Exchange Algorithm, where no one draws themselves). To eliminate "interior" matches where two people draw each other, apparently the "Blossom" algorithm is required (I knew when I saw Joey Lawrence this would get back to Blossom) : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm

Comment: @Anthony Can you please explain where in this scenario the algorithm would fail (except if there's only one guy)?

Comment: In which scenario? The code you provided or one of the dorky algorithms I commented with? Your algorithm is fine, though a bit intimidating to look at.

Comment: @Anthony Yeah, *my* algorithm. :) OK, just wanted to make sure I didn't overlook anything. And this is intimidating? I find this a lot easier on the eyes than loops with cryptic iterator variables... ;)

Comment: @deceze - I'm impressed you did it all with built in array functions, no doubt. I always feel intimidated by simple code (read: code made of simple parts I already know) that I don't get right away how it works. Was also taken aback by how quick you spit that out.  I was just trying to visualize the arrangement of the members and couldn't and once I saw flowers and graphs, I'll take yours.

Comment: @Anthony Piece of cake if you're used to thinking in terms of more abstract data sets... ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40493/discussion-between-anthony-and-deceze)

Answer (score 0):

I found this post: [Using PHP, randomly pair up group of items, not pairing any with itself, no direct pairings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758223/using-php-randomly-pair-up-group-of-items-not-pairing-any-with-itself-no-dire)

And the top answer looks very good: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3758775/623952

```
// result array
$res = array();
// get first element and save it
$first = $ele1 = array_shift($arr);
while(count($arr)) {
    // get random element
    $ele2 = array_rand($arr);
    // associate elements
    $res[$ele1] = $arr[$ele2];
    // random element becomes next element
    $ele1 = $arr[$ele2];
    // delete the random element
    array_splice($arr, $ele2, 1);
}
// associate last element woth the first one
$res[$ele1] = $first;
```

that gives me:

```
Array
(
    [lawrence] => joel
    [joel] => joey
    [joey] => jason
    [jason] => paulo
    [paulo] => albert
    [albert] => bianca
    [bianca] => lawrence
)
```

You might need a check in there to see if the "the person selects themselves" in your gift exchange.

Comment: @ gloomy.penguin thanks and the one you answered recently was also working

Comment: @LawrenceBoadilla I see that that the other person provided a solution your issue already (green checkmark) but you seem to still be discussing problems in the comments... is there anything I could add to this code to solve your question as a whole?

Comment: @actually the algorithm by deceze already works fine, i just didnt get it in the first place to begin with. i thought it was using rot13 sort of like algo.