# Randomly generate pair team, not pairing with itself

Tags: php, random, generator

I want to generate a pairing structure for that i have only n(number of team) and level(n-1)

Please see the screenshot:
First the Quarterfinal round there are 8 team each team paired with randomly.

Quarterfinals:

```
 Austria->paired with = Hungary
 Czech Republic->paired with = New Zealang
 France->paired with = Belgium
 Estonia->paired with = Iceland
```

[image]

Using PHP, how would you randomly pair the team together without pairing them with a duplicate of themselves?

**EDIT:** All eight team coming from database.

Comment: Is the team information coming from a database, because there is an easy way to do this with sql?

Comment: @gprusiiski Yes that all team coming from database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the teams list, you can add then to a zero based array. Following given code sample can be modified to fit your requirement. Change/modify it for your case to get teams dynamically and handle odd/even team counts. Following for loop will work only with even team counts so the rest is for you.

```
$teams[] = "Austria";
$teams[] = "Hungary";
$teams[] = "Czech Republic";
$teams[] = "New Zealang";
$teams[] = "France";
$teams[] = "Belgium";
$teams[] = "Estonia";
$teams[] = "Iceland";

$number_of_teams = count($teams);
// Shuffle the teams
shuffle($teams);// You get a shuffled array

// Pair the adjacent teams
for ( $index = 0; $index < $number_of_teams; $index +=2) {
    // Pair $teams[$index ] with $teams[$index +1]
    echo $teams[$index ] . "->paired with = " . $teams[$index+1] . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ShanthaKumara Can you solve the same question but different is how to manage the structure? link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21234703/randomly-generate-a-pair-with-tournament-tree-structure-among-players?noredirect=1#comment31986189_21234703

Answer (score 0):

Use a random shuffle, not a random pick.  Put the eight teams into an array and shuffle the array.  That way you are guaranteed no duplicates, every team still appears once but in a different order.

Comment: Dear @rossum Your answer correct but i want to know how to use this in php code? Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758223/using-php-randomly-pair-up-group-of-items-not-pairing-any-with-itself-no-dire