# I'm trying to make a match generator in Laravel. But every team appears twice in the output

Tags: php, laravel

Im making a match generator in Laravel. I have an array named $matches. The problem is that when I output the code every team plays twice. The code I use is shown below.

```
public function generateMatches($allContestants){
    $matches = [];
    
    for ($i=0; $i < count($allContestants) -1; $i++) { 
        $matches[] = [
            'team1' => $allContestants[$i]->id,
            'team2' => $allContestants[$i+1]->id
        ];
    }
    dd($matches);
}
```

This is the output I get:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "team1" => "1"
    "team2" => "10"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "team1" => "10"
    "team2" => "11"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "team1" => "11"
    "team2" => "12"
  ]
]
```

As you can see the second team of every match is the first one used in the next match. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your logic of looping through the array (and not generating it randomly) you could increase $i by 2 instead of 1 every time.

```
public function generateMatches($allContestants){
    $matches = [];
    
    for ($i=0; $i < count($allContestants) - 2; $i += 2) { 
        $matches[] = [
            'team1' => $allContestants[$i]->id,
            'team2' => $allContestants[$i+1]->id
        ];
    }
    dd($matches);
}
```

The only problem you will now have is to define what happens if the amount of contestans is not even.

With regards to doing it randomly you can have a look at this post: [Using PHP, randomly pair up group of items, not pairing any with itself, no direct pairings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758223/using-php-randomly-pair-up-group-of-items-not-pairing-any-with-itself-no-dire)

Comment: That fixed the problem. Thank you very much!